# Android video recording issue using surfaceview and media recorder on galaxy note2

Tags: java, android, android-4.4-kitkat, video-recording

I am working on a custom camera using surface view, but i am getting some strange issue while recording video,

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.dts.stallchat.activities.ImageCameraActivity$9.onClick(ImageCameraActivity.java:304)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4222)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17620)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Code implemented

```
//Release Camera before MediaRecorder start
            releaseCamera();

                  if(!prepareMediaRecorder()){
                   Toast.makeText(_thisActivity,
                     "Fail in prepareMediaRecorder()!\n - Ended -",
                     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   //finish();
                  }

                  /*if(mediaRecorder==null){
                      mediaRecorder= new MediaRecorder();
                  }*/

                  recordingTime.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    recordingTime.start();
                    recordingTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            mediaRecorder.start(); // this is line 304
            is_recording = true;`
```

Methods:

```
 private void releaseMediaRecorder(){
       if (mediaRecorder != null) {
           mediaRecorder.reset();   // clear recorder configuration
           mediaRecorder.release(); // release the recorder object
           mediaRecorder = null;
           camera.lock();           // lock camera for later use
       }
   }

   private void releaseCamera(){
       if (camera != null){
           camera.release();        // release the camera for other applications
           camera = null;
       }
   }
 private boolean prepareMediaRecorder(){ 
     try{ 
         camera = getCameraInstance();

            Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();


             int displayOrt=setGetCameraDisplayOrientation(_thisActivity, currentCameraId, camera);

             if(!parameters.getFlashMode().equalsIgnoreCase(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF)){
                 parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
             }else {
                parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
            }

             Camera.Size prevSize=StallchatCameraUtils.getBestAspectPreviewSize(displayOrt, wid, wid, parameters);
           // Camera.Size prevSize=getBestPreviewSize(wid, wid, parameters);
            parameters.setPreviewSize(prevSize.width, prevSize.height);
            camera.setParameters(parameters);

             mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

             camera.unlock();
             mediaRecorder.setCamera(camera);
            // mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
             mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
             mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
             //mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
             //mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(wid, wid);
             //mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);

             mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));

             mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getVideoPath().getAbsolutePath());
               mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(60000); // Set max duration 60 sec.
               mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(20000000); // Set max file size 20M

               //cameraSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

             mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(cameraSurfaceHolder.getSurface());

     }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
         e.printStackTrace();
         return false;
    }



     try {
         mediaRecorder.prepare();
     } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
         releaseMediaRecorder();
         return false;
     } catch (IOException e) {
         releaseMediaRecorder();
         return false;
     }
     return true;

 }
```

I getting this issue on following devices -

Samsung Note 2 (android 4.4.2)

Micromax A114 (android 4.2.2)

But in other device like  motorola moto g (4.4.4)

or samsung galaxy s2 working nice

Comment: Can you show me your code for getVideoPath()? Because i am having same code as yours for video recording but i am not able to make it work with Motorola moto g (4.4.4). But it is working nice for me on android 4.4.2

Answer (score 0):

paste android:hardwareAccelerated="false" into your manifest file.